# Submit on rails returning a strange path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, submit

Since I've started programming in Rails 5 days ago. I'm learning very many aspects of the framework by seeing its behaviour around my tests, the answers were perfect but this time I've got this one and I dont know what to do with it:
The message that I've got is this one...

> undefined method `task_task_task_task_task_path' for #<#:0x36df6c8>

This is my view:

```
<%= form_for @tasks do |t| %>
<div id="task_list">
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li id="task">
  <% if task.done == false %> 
    <%= t.check_box :done, :checked => task.done, :checked_value => true, :unchecked_value => false %>  <%= task.name %>
  <% else %>
    <%= t.check_box :done, :checked => task.done, :checked_value => true, :unchecked_value => false, :disabled => "disabled" %>  <%= task.name + "(done)" %>
  <% end %> 

  </li>
<% end %>
<%= t.submit "Mark selected as done", :action => "update" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I've already checked the form and submit documentation many times but I can't get it. This form is for many instances and update every instance with a new boolean value.

Thanks already.

Comment: Rails isn't expecting you to use form_for like that - it's expecting to be passed a (possibly namespaces) single record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't magically submit an array of data to a server, Rails form helpers are for individual objects, not for collections.

There are ways, however, to submit an array of values back to the server,for example you can append [] to checkbox name attribute, this will force rails to create an array of values on server side.

For a detailed discussion, please see [this documentation point 7.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)